# How should simulator time be logged in a pilot logbook?

Tags: faa-regulations, logging, flight-simulator

In a full motion Level C or D simulator like those used by the airlines and for jet type ratings:

[image: A380 simulator]

How should a pilot log the simulator time in their logbook?  I.e. Can you log:

- Total Time
- Instrument Time
- Time in Type
- Cross Country Time
- Night Time
- Landings (including night landings)
- Dual given/received
- Anything else?

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, as you've tagged it as FAA repated, but maybe nice to know and still helpfull: In EASA logbooks there is an extra culum for so called synthetic trainig devices, where we log our time in any kind of approved simulator. There is no difference between FNPT or full flight. This time is completely independent of the other flight times, but can still be used to stay current on type if the hours are loged in a full flight.

Comment: I always logged it as simulator time. Though those high level sims are as realistic as the actual aircraft they model.

Comment: @Shawn That they are.  I know that some of the others are allowed too but not sure on all of them!

Answer (score 3):

You log simulated instrument time in an FFS, Full Flight Simulator.
The relevant FAR's are 61.4, 61.1(b)6.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.flyingd.net/documents/LOGGINGSIMULATORTIMEcopy.pdf

This link provides good information of logging simulator time.

I copied and pasted the article below.

> LOGGING SIMULATOR TIME One thing that generates more questions than
>   anything else (besides FAA certification) is the proper way to log
>   training time on an ATD. Here's a basic framework: In the "N" number
>   column, put the type/model of simulator. This lets an examiner know
>   the simulator is a BATD or an AATD (Advanced Aviation Training Device)
>   and is eligible for the time towards a certificate or rating. It's
>   also a good idea to provide a current copy of the LOA to clients to
>   show to the examiner.
>
> In the "Type" column: Record the actual aircraft make/model flown in
>   the simulator (TAKEWING’S IS A C182RG). This is required information
>   as some examiners only allow multi-engine AATD time to count towards a
>   commercial ticket if flying in a multi-engine aircraft.
>
> In the "To" and "From" columns: Record the airports used during
>   training (77S etc.).
>
> The "SEL," "MEL," "Day/Night" and "Cross-Country" columns should
>   remain blank. These columns are designated for actual aircraft flight
>   only. Similarly, do not log landings (i.e. 90-day day/night landing
>   currency cannot be performed in an AATD).
>
> In the "Approach" column: Log the number of approaches performed in
>   the simulator. The criteria for an approach is the same as in an
>   aircraft, passing the FAF in IMC and breaking out at or above DA/MDA
>   with a subsequent landing or executed missed approach.
>
> In the actual IMC Column: No time is logged.
>
> In simulated IMC (hood or IMC in an ATD): Log the actual time in IMC.
>   For example, in a 1.8 hour session, it might be typical to log about
>   1.5 hours of simulated IMC.  In the "FTD" or "Flight Simulator" column, log the total time in the ATD.
>
> In the "PIC" and "Total Flight" columns: log all time as this shows
>   the pilot experience time. An examiner can see the time under
>   "SEL/MEL" for actual aircraft time and the time under "FTD" or "Flight
>   Simulator" for simulator time. The combination of both of these is the
>   pilot experience. In the "Dual" column, log the entire dual training
>   time in the ATD.
>
> Adhering to these guidelines should insure full credit for valid
>   training hours in an ATD.

Comment: This all sounds reasonable, except that in the simulators that I refer to you are allowed to log landings, and the visuals can be set to day/night so I *believe*, but am not sure, that you can log night time as well.

Comment: @Lnafziger faa form 8710-1 has the logged-time matrix generally relevent to legal logging requirements (As opposed to the requirements of specific operations like a 141 program), then add to this the specific needs of currency, like approaches. ATD is only good for logging total sim time, dual received, and instrument approaches. FTD time can be logged as night PIC, and full flight sims can also log night takeoffs and landings. Single engine or multi engine configuration should be noted and the types tallied separately (land or sea is irrelevant for sim logging) for 6 totals SE/ME*ATD/FTD/FFS